# pageWorker does not work with all pages on Facebook

Tags: jquery, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

i'm writing a firefox extension to read out privacy settings. I use PageWorkers to navigate through different websites. However, some are working find and other sites won't open.

```
function visitWebsite(url, flowURL){
var profile_website = pageWorkers.Page({
  contentURL: url,
  contentScriptFile: [data.url('jquery-1.6.4.js'),
                      flowURL,
                      data.url('extract_algorithm.js'),
                      data.url('ProfileSettings/profile_controller.js')],
  contentScriptWhen: "ready"
});

//event triggers, when all profile settings were loaded from a site from profile_controller
profile_website.port.on('profile_results', function(profile_results){    
    add_to_all_results(profile_results);
});
}


function checkProfileSettings(){
visitWebsite("http://www.facebook.com/editprofile.php?sk=basic", data.url('ProfileSettings/Flow_Site1.js'));
visitWebsite("http://www.facebook.com/editprofile.php?sk=relationships", data.url('ProfileSettings/Flow_Site2.js'));
visitWebsite("http://www.facebook.com/editprofile.php?sk=eduwork", data.url('ProfileSettings/Flow_Site3.js'));
visitWebsite("http://www.facebook.com/editprofile.php?sk=philosophy", data.url('ProfileSettings/Flow_Site4.js'));
visitWebsite("http://www.facebook.com/editprofile.php?sk=entertainment", data.url('ProfileSettings/Flow_Site5.js'));
visitWebsite("http://www.facebook.com/editprofile.php?sk=sports", data.url('ProfileSettings/Flow_Site6.js'));
visitWebsite("http://www.facebook.com/editprofile.php?sk=activities", data.url('ProfileSettings/Flow_Site7.js'));
visitWebsite("http://www.facebook.com/editprofile.php?sk=contact", data.url('ProfileSettings/Flow_Site8.js')); 
}
```

The `Flow_SiteX.js` contains the parameter for the readout, but I tested it with `console.log($('.label').text()))` in the profile_controller.js. In every site are at least 1 class with `.label` so there should be an output. The Sites Basic, Relationships, Philosophy, entertainment are always working perfectly. But the PageWorker seems not to open sports or activities at all!? Sometimes eduwork is working and sometimes it does not.
Well, I don't understand why some sites are working and some not... I tried the `checkProfileSettings()` with only sports for example, because I thought the memory or something was full but it didn't work either...

Thank you! :)

Edit: I wrote a little Test

main.js

```
var data = require("self").data;
var pageWorkers = require("page-worker");
var timers = require("timers");

function TestvisitWebsite(url, flowURL){
var profile_website = pageWorkers.Page({
  contentURL: url,
  contentScriptFile: [data.url('jquery-1.6.4.js'),
                      data.url('script.js')],
  contentScriptWhen: "ready"
});
}
function testcheck()
{
  TestvisitWebsite("http://www.facebook.com/editprofile.php?sk=sports", "aaa");    
}
var timeout = timers.setInterval(function() 
{
    testcheck();
}, 1000);
```

script.js:

```
function combobox_by_name(ID_of_name){
console.log("Testoutput - " + $('select[name=audience\\[' + ID_of_name + '\\]\\[value\\]] option:selected').text());
}

combobox_by_name(129991670408857);
```

well and the funny output looks like this:

[image: Output]

Freunde is german for "friends" and is the correct output, however only sometimes!? And when I try it with http://www.facebook.com/editprofile.php?sk=basic for example, it works always!

Comment: It might be a good idea to install [HttpFox](https://addons.mozilla.org/addon/httpfox/) extension and to check what is actually being loaded and how the server responds.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I wrote a little test for the sports and it's working about 40% of the time. I checked it with HttpFox and he gets the right page with full content **every** time... so the pageworker gets the full page correctly, but he only scannes it sometimes!? and the funny thing is, that it's only on some pages?? is there maybe a known bug with pageworkers?

Answer (score 0):

It could be a race condition (ie facebook loads the element that you are looking for sometime after the ready event)